# Unable to pass ajax to controller function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to update my database using ajax in laravel. When i click the button (toggle button) it should update the database enable column from 1 to 0.

Here is the script written in the view

```
$(".toggle-btn").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('name'); // $(this) refers to button that was clicked

    $.ajax({
        url: '/adminpanel/dviulaan/stt',
        method: "post",
        data: {'id' : id} ,
        dataType: "json",

      });
});
```

Here is my route

```
    Route::post('adminpanel/dviulaan/stt', 'AdminDvAnnouncement@status');
```

And here is the controller function

```
public function status()
{
    $id = Input::all();

 if (Request::ajax()) {
    DvAnnouncement::where('announcement_id', $id)->update(
        [
            'enable' => '0',
            'user_updated' => Auth::user()->id,
            'updated_at' => new DateTime,
        ]);
}

        $response = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'Option created successfully',
        );

        return Response::json( $response );

}
```

When i click the button it shows the following error in the consol

```
POST http://localhost/adminpanel/dviulaan/stt 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Please help me to find the error.

I have even changed the controller method as below

```
public function status(Request $request)
    {
        $id = Input::get('id');

     if (Request::ajax()) {
        DvAnnouncement::where('announcement_id', $id)->update(
            [
                'enable' => '0',
                'user_updated' => Auth::user()->id,
                'updated_at' => new DateTime,
            ]);
    }

            $response = array(
                'status' => 'success',
                'msg' => 'Option created successfully',
            );

            return Response::json( $response );

    }
```

Comment: That means your PHP is failing. Check the error logs on the server for more information.

Comment: im confused. everything works fine except this.

Comment: If you read your server's error logs you will become less confused. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\adcity\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illumi‌​nate\Foundation\Http‌​\Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(‌​Object(Illuminate\Ht‌​tp\Request)) #41 C:\xampp\htdocs\adcity\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\‌​Http\Request)) #42 {main}

Comment: You're only posting the last line of the error, ideally we need the first!

Comment: [2016-10-15 00:06:56] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in C:\xampp\htdocs\adducity\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php:67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$id = Input::all();` => `$id = Input::get('id');`

**UPD** after logs

include in head

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
```

then change in function

```
$(".toggle-btn").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('name'); // $(this) refers to button that was clicked

  $.ajax({
    url: '/adminpanel/dviulaan/stt',
    method: "post",
    data: {'id' : id, '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')} ,
    dataType: "json",

  });
});
```

Comment: oh. thats a mistake. ive corrected it. but still it gives the same error message

Comment: Look last log file in directory storage/logs, may be error in database

Comment: `Auth::user()->id` user auth? Because if not, then `Auth::user()` return `null` and it will be error

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\adducity\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 C:\xampp\htdocs\adducity\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 {main}

Comment: ' 
C:\xampp\htdocs\adducity\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illumi‌​nate\Foundation\Http‌​\Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(‌​Object(Illuminate\Ht‌​tp\Request)) #41 C:\xampp\htdocs\adducity\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\‌​Http\Request)) #42 {main}'

Comment: use is authenticated. even when i removed that line, still it gives the same error

Comment: If you remove query `DvAnnouncement::where(...`, is work fine?

Comment: 2016-10-15 00:06:56] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in C:\xampp\htdocs\adducity\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illumi‌​nate\Foundation\Http‌​\Middleware\VerifyCs‌​rfToken.php:67

Comment: 'data: {'id' : id, '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');} ,' 
is this correct? 

there is semicolon before the last curly bracket.

Comment: `data: {'id' : id, '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')} ,`

Comment: it gives the same error message in the consol.

BUT now it updates the database

Comment: `[2016-10-15 00:32:17] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Response' not found' in C:\xampp\htdocs\adducity\app\Http\Controllers\AdminDvAnnouncement.php:82
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  `

Comment: change `return Response::json( $response );` => `return \Response::json( $response );`

Comment: oh i forget to  insert the `use Response;` at the beginning.
SOLVED THE PROBLEM


THANK YOU